# Why was Hamaji bleeding?

Tags: fuse

After Hamaji receives the letter from the Fusé Dousetsu then beheads her. shortly after Dousetsu notices a small trickle of blood coming from Hamaji nose before she goes to cover her nose, this is when more blood start to come out.

Why was Hamaji bleeding from her nose? was it related to seeing Dousetsu behead the Fusé?